# Count word ocurrences in each row using Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a set of tweets that have many different fields

```
raw_tweets = LOAD 'input.tsv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (tweet_id, text, 
in_reply_to_status_id, favorite_count, source, coordinates, entities, 
in_reply_to_screen_name, in_reply_to_user_id, retweet_count, is_retweet, 
retweet_of_id, user_id_id, lang, created_at, event_id_id, is_news);
```

I want to find the most common words for each date. I managed to group the texts by date:

```
r1 = FOREACH raw_tweets GENERATE SUBSTRING(created_at,0,10) AS a, REPLACE 
(LOWER(text),'([^a-z\\s]+)','') AS b;
r2 = group r1 by a;
r3 = foreach r2 generate group as a, r1 as b;
r4 = foreach r3 generate a, FLATTEN(BagToTuple(b.b));
```

Now it looks like:

```
(date text text3)
(date2 text2)
```

I removed the special characters, so only "real" words appear in the text. 
Sample:

```
2017-06-18 the plants are green the dog is black there are words this is
2017-06-19 more words and even more words another phrase begins here
```

I want the output to look like

```
2017-06-18 the are is
2017-06-19 more words and
```

I don't really care about how many times the word appears. I just want to show the most common, if two words appear the same amount of times, show any of them.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more than one sample row. Also your expected output

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry, I fixed that

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the given input? Are you able to use Python written udfs?

Comment: @cricket_007 I edited that. Yes, I can use UDFs but I have no experience with them.

Comment: Good first question! You'd be amazed how many people ask on SO without any clue how to ask... although to be fair most of the dodgy questions seem to come from non-English speakers, so it would be more difficult for them to make a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm sure there is a way to do this entirely in Pig, it would probably be more difficult than necessary.

[**UDFs**](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/udf.html) are the way to go, in my opinion, and Python is just one option I will show because it's quick to register it in Pig.

For example,

`input.tsv`

```
2017-06-18  the plants are green the dog is black there are words this is
2017-06-19  more words and even more words another phrase begins here
```

`py_udfs.py`

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

@outputSchema("y:bag{t:tuple(word:chararray,count:int)}")
def word_count(sentence):
    ''' Does a word count of a sentence and orders common words first '''
    words = Counter()
    for w in sentence.split():
        words[w] += 1
    values = ((word,count) for word,count in words.items())
    return sorted(values,key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

`script.pig`

```
REGISTER 'py_udfs.py' USING jython AS py_udfs;
A = LOAD 'input.tsv' USING PigStorage('\t') as (created_at:chararray,sentence:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE created_at, py_udfs.word_count(sentence);
\d B
```

Output

```
(2017-06-18,{(is,2),(the,2),(are,2),(green,1),(black,1),(words,1),(this,1),(plants,1),(there,1),(dog,1)})
(2017-06-19,{(more,2),(words,2),(here,1),(another,1),(begins,1),(phrase,1),(even,1),(and,1)})
```

If you are doing textual analysis, though, I would suggest

- Removing stop words
- Lemmatization / stemming
- Use Apache Spark